# Post data returning null

Tags: posts, pages

I'm writing code from within a plugin and I'm attempting to create a two-part registration form. I'm using POST to determine if the first part of the form was submitted or not. Unfortunately, though, the POST data is not coming through. Here is what my form looks like:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="user_info_form" id="user_info_form" />
</form>
```

This should POST back to the same page, in theory. I then use the below code to read the POST data.

```
if(isset($_POST['user_info_form']))
{
echo "found data";
}
else
{
echo "nothing found";
}
```

Unfortunately, "nothing found" is being outputted following a form submission.

Is there any reason for this that has to do with WordPress? I've been at this for hours now so any help is *very* much appreciated!

Comment: what do you get when you `print_r( $_POST )`?

Comment: I'm getting all of the other POST data, so that seems to be working okay. However, I'm not getting the submit button's post data which means it's not being sent to the right place maybe? What should the action of the form be?

Comment: try just `action=''`, see if that gets the post data in there

Comment: That was the first thing I tried :)

Comment: If you use Chrome's 'Inspect Element' tool (or equivalent in your browser of choice), what do you see for the action of the form?

Comment: This is what inspect element shows:

<form action="#" method="POST">
 ...          
        </form>

Comment: I wonder if the # might be your issue...try changing that manually (in the inspect tool) and seeing if that makes it submit

Comment: I've already got this working - see my answer below.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Answer didn't float to the top for some reason...glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer on this one (just now). The stupid plugin had javascript at the bottom of the page disabling all submit buttons from working - what a joke, sorry everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a value to the input field? It looks like you are using a submit input field, not a text input field. *<- Never mind, it still isn't null after submitting.*

In order to troubleshoot, try adding the following to the top of your code:

```
<?php
echo 'Post variables:<br />';
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Also, where are you placing this code? I dropped your code straight in to the header.php file of a custom theme and it worked as expected.

Comment: Yes, I'm checking to see if the submit button was clicked. I do not care about the text field. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Actually, I just checked, even with no specified value in the submit input field, I'm still seeing 'Submit' come through. I've edited above, have a look.

Comment: Sorry, but what did you edit? I don't see any changes :)

Comment: Check again, was sidetracked...

Comment: All of the code you see there is inside of a plugin file which I believe becomes part of a page (I'm 99.99% positive about that). So, to answer your question, I'm posting and retrieving the post from inside of a wordpress page. What should I be putting in the header??

Comment: I have a question, what happens if you rename the field user_info_form to something completely random like apple_wheels? I was just thinking it could be a conflict if you or something else is storing a $_SESSION variable with the same name as user_info_form.

Comment: Also, I was just saying the header because it gives easy access to executing PHP code straight without any interference.

Comment: I tried the apple_wheels thing and the same problem. I'm sure something is blocking my POST data but I have no other plugins installed.

Comment: I will give you the +100 for trying so hard on this one ..

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a hidden input field to the code?

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form_submitted" />
    <input type="submit" name="user_info_form" id="user_info_form" />
</form>
```

Then compare to the hidden field's value. Does that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="user_info_form" id="user_info_form" />
</form>
```

I think there is a syntax error in the PHP. It should end with a semicolon, like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="user_info_form" id="user_info_form" />
</form>
```

Comment: [not a syntax error.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)